# How do you start a running race in Spanish?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, deportes

> One, two, three, go!

This is how we would start a running race, or other games or competitions in the UK, so that everyone starts together.  What is the Spanish equivalent?

Answer (score 15):

It is going to be difficult to find a "source" for this... But what I am used to is

- Preparados... Listos... ¡Ya!

as a translation for "Ready... Set... Go!" (see for example a [newspaper article](https://elpais.com/sociedad/2020-04-30/preparados-listos-ya.html) titled like that), or

- Tres... Dos... Uno... ¡Ya!

or

- Uno... Dos... Tres... ¡Ya!

as a translation for "three, two, one, go!" or "one, two, three, go!" respectively. There even seems to be a Spanish learning book titled ["Uno, dos, tres, ¡ya!"](https://www.google.com/search?q=uno%20dos%20tres%20ya).

Answer (score 15):

In Latin America the common translation is:

> En sus marcas >> Listos (Preparados) >> Fuera(Ya)

Comment: This seems like a direct translation of the American English "On your mark, get set, go!"

Comment: Yes, i do think they share the same origin. Still have not found any convincing document to prove it, tho.

Comment: It is more or less an international standard. Olympic races start "On your marks, set, <gunshot>"